# An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'ODBC' that is either not registered

Tags: reporting-services, odbc

I am using ODBC external database in SSRS reports, it works fine in the data tools  in design and preview mode, but when deployed the problem starts. In security when i try to test connection giving connection string and all the credentials required for a ODBC database it says "**"The data extension used here is not available. It has either been uninstalled, or it is not configured correctly."** and in the error details it says **An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'ODBC' that is either not registered for this report server or is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services.**. Can anyone help me how to fix this error. I searched alot but could find an answer..

Comment: One thing to check, you have to have the ODBC connection correct on your PC where you are developing the report and running it and then also on the actual reporting SQL Server.

Comment: yeah, the connection is correct, when i do test connection it shows successful. I can see the reports in preview  in visual studio data tool but not when i deploy the reports.

Comment: Does SSRS supports ODBC, I see multiple discussions with similar question but none of them have been notified as correct answer. Can we use ODBC database after configuring in the ssrs report

Comment: Try; https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0c00012f-c423-4cfe-b3a0-434f86823b5e/how-to-avoid-quotthe-data-processing-extension-used-for-this-report-is-not-available-it-has?forum=sqlreportingservices